# How to dynamically get a property by name from a C# ExpandoObject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, dynamic, reflection

I have an `ExpandoObject` and want to make a getter for it that will return a property by name at runtime, where the name is specified in a string instead of hardcoded.

For example, I CAN do this:

```
account.features.isEmailEnabled;
```

and that will return true.  `account` is a `ExpandoObject`, and `features` is also an `ExpandoObject`.  So I have an `ExpandoObject` that contains other `ExpandoObjects`.

So what I want to be able to do is this:

```
account.features.GetProperty("isEmailEnabled");
```

and have that return true.

The reason is that I have many features, and I want to be able to write one generic getter method where I can pass in the name of the feature I want, and the method will pass me back the value for account.features.whatever (where "whatever" is specified by passing in a string to the generic getter method).  Otherwise I am going to have to write 30-some getters one for each feature.

I did a lot of research and tried doing something like:

```
var prop = account.features.GetType();  
// this returns System.Dyanmic.ExpandoObject
```

followed by

```
var value = prop.GetProperty(featureNameAsString);
```

but `value` always comes back as null. I don't understand why. In the watch window I can do `account.features.isEmailEnabled` and it shows true and says its a boolean.  But if I try to get at this value using the approach above and pass in `isEmailEnabled` as the `featureNameAsString` I just get null.

Can someone please tell me what I may be doing wrong and what's a good approach, without it being too complex?

I am working with ASP.NET under the 4.5.1 framework.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` provides access both via `dynamic` and via `IDictionary<string,object>` - so you could just use the dictionary API:

```
var byName = (IDictionary<string,object>)account.features;
bool val = (bool)byName["isEmailEnabled"];
```

Or if the name is fixed, just:

```
bool val = ((dynamic)account).features.isEmailEnabled;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an extension method to do what you need:

```
public static T Get<T>(this ExpandoObject expO, string prop)
{
    return (T)((IDictionary<string, object>)expO)[prop];
}
```

Example usage:

```
account.features.Get<bool>("isEmailEnabled");
```