# GetProperty return Null for property that I see in debug

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-6.0, getproperty

GetProperty method returns null, but I 100% sure that property I try to get exists, because I see it in debug.

I have List of dynamic rows that I get from CSV file. I need to get property value for specific row. To do that I use next code.

```
Type type = row.GetType();
PropertyInfo property = type.GetProperty("Site");
string propertyValue = property.GetValue(row);
```

But as result I receive "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." when GetValue runs. In debug I see this property and it's value for the row variable (screenshot attached). Also if I change code and try to get property directly everything works fine.

```
string propertyValue = row.Site;
```

[image: Debug screenshot]

But I can not use this approach because in the future I need to get property value by variable.

I am new in C# and .NET, please give an advice how to solve this problem.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139417/how-to-dynamically-get-a-property-by-name-from-a-c-sharp-expandoobject

Comment: Thank you! This approach works fine. Now it's clear for me.