# Getting values of ExpandoObject from Keys that are known at runtime

Tags: c#, csvhelper, expandoobject

I am using `CsvHelper` to read a `CSV` file so I can write "some" of its columns to somewhere else. I **don't** have the name of headers beforehand so I couldn't use `ClassMapper` . However I can get a List of the names of columns at **runtime** because **they are provided in a separate file** so if I can read that file I can fill up a `List<string>` with name of the headers of the `CSV` that I am reading.

My question is now how can I use Key names of the ExpandoObject so I can get the value from them?  Remember at runtime I do have a `List<string>` that holds the keys/header names.

The two commented-out lines below are **what I tried** but failed.

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("LastName");
using(var streamReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\csvtesting\myfile.csv"))
{
    using(var csvReader = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var records = csvReader.GetRecords<dynamic>().ToList();
        var one = records.First();
        //one.Where(v => v.Key == list[0]).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault(); // cannot cast error
        //var ddd = one.list[0]; // crash
        var iWish = one.LastName; // but how to do this dynamically?
    }
}
```

Comment: I generally go digging around `ExpandoObject`s using the fact that that class implements `IDictionary<string, object>`. Cast it to an IDictionary and then use `TryGetValue`

Comment: Seconding the idea to cast to `IDictionary<string, object>` from @Flydog57.  See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19139499) by Marc Gravell to [How to dynamically get a property by name from a C# ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19139417) which suggests the same, so close as a duplicate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically get a property by name from a C# ExpandoObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139417/how-to-dynamically-get-a-property-by-name-from-a-c-sharp-expandoobject)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use the fact that underlying type of `dynamic` in this case would be `ExpandoObject` which [implements `IDictionary<string, object>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-7.0):

```cs
var one = records.First() as IDictionary<string, object>;
var iWish = one[list[0]]; // or TryGetValue, also can check the headers
```

Note that you can process the csv "dynamically" without using `dynamic` (which, I would argue, in general case should be avoided) but using `while` loop and `GetField` API (see the [Reading by Hand](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/reading/reading-by-hand/) doc):

```cs
using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Read();
    csv.ReadHeader();
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        string? iWish = csv.GetField(list[0]);
        string? iWishByIndex = csv.GetField(0); // if it is first column
        break; // just for sake of the example
    }
}
```